# MySQL: Limit by a group of rows, not by a row

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MySQL table like the following. The `id` and `name` fields are just here to help identify the row, `l` represents many other fields whit not relevant data, and `lat` and `lng` are used to find duplicated entries.

```
CREATE TABLE v
    (`id` int, `lat` int, `lng` int, `l` varchar(3), `name` varchar(8))
;

INSERT INTO v
    (`id`, `lat`, `lng`, `l`, `name`)
VALUES
    ( 1, 12, 12, 'a', 'group1-1'),
    ( 2, 12, 12, 'b', 'group1-2'),
    ( 3, 13, 12, 'c', 'single1'),
    ( 4, 13, 13, 'd', 'group2-1'),
    ( 5, 13, 13, 'e', 'group2-2'),
    ( 6, 13, 13, 'f', 'group2-3'),
    ( 7, 10, 13, 'g', 'group3-1'),
    ( 8, 10, 13, 'h', 'group3-2'),
    ( 9, 11, 12, 'h', 'group4-1'),
    (10, 11, 12, 'h', 'group4-2'),
    (11, 10, 14, 'i', 'group5-1'),
    (12, 10, 14, 'j', 'group5-2'),
    (13, 10, 14, 'j', 'group5-3')
;
```

Now I want to get all rows where there is more than one row with the same lat and lng values (let's call that a group):

```
SELECT v.*
FROM v
 INNER JOIN (
  SELECT lat, lng
  FROM v
  GROUP BY lat, lng
  HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
  ) AS vg
  USING (lat, lng)
ORDER BY name
;
```

Outputs:

```
ID  LAT LNG L   NAME
1   12  12  a   group1-1
2   12  12  b   group1-2
4   13  13  d   group2-1
5   13  13  e   group2-2
6   13  13  f   group2-3
7   10  13  g   group3-1
8   10  13  h   group3-2
9   11  12  h   group4-1
10  11  12  h   group4-2
11  10  14  i   group5-1
12  10  14  j   group5-2
13  10  14  j   group5-3
```

Works well so far, all but the "single1" rows are selected and ordered by group.

Now I want to add a limit to form different pages of this data. But all rows of the same group need to be on the same page (but not one page per group and it doesn't matter how many rows actually are on one page - just not too many). I don't see this done with a LIMIT statement, so I started to write my own:

```
SET @grp := 0, @last_lat := '', @last_lng := '';

SELECT * FROM (
 SELECT v.*,
  @grp := IF((@last_lat = lat) && (@last_lng = lng), @grp, @grp + 1) AS grp,
  @last_lat := lat AS llat,
  @last_lng := lng AS llng
 FROM v
  INNER JOIN (
   SELECT lat, lng
   FROM v
   GROUP BY lat, lng
   HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
   ) AS vg
   USING (lat, lng) 
 ORDER BY lat, lng
) AS vv
WHERE grp BETWEEN 0 AND 7
ORDER BY grp
;
```

This query whit out the WHERE part outputs this data:

```
ID  LAT LNG L   NAME        GRP LLAT    LLNG
1   12  12  a   group1-1    6   12  12
2   12  12  b   group1-2    6   12  12
5   13  13  e   group2-2    7   13  13
6   13  13  f   group2-3    7   13  13
4   13  13  d   group2-1    7   13  13
7   10  13  g   group3-1    8   10  13
8   10  13  h   group3-2    8   10  13
10  11  12  h   group4-2    9   11  12
9   11  12  h   group4-1    9   11  12
13  10  14  j   group5-3    10  10  14
11  10  14  i   group5-1    10  10  14
12  10  14  j   group5-2    10  10  14
```

The idea is to change the values in the line WHERE grp BETWEEN 0 AND 7 for each page. But the numbers from the group don't start at 1 and I can't see why (and that makes it unusable for the first page). The Start number is different depending on how many group are in the whole data. So what I need to have, is that the grp column start whit 1 and then continues whit always +1.

What is wrong with this query and are there any better ways to do this?

You can play whit this query here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!8/86d3c/2

Comment: Can you please post the expected result(s) based on your sample data?

Comment: @PM77-1 I added the output and some more explanation.

Answer (score 1):

```
SET @grp := 0, @last_lat := '', @last_lng := '';

SELECT vv.*,@grp-grp+1 as orgGrp FROM (
 SELECT v.*,
  @grp := IF((@last_lat = lat) && (@last_lng = lng), @grp, @grp + 1) AS grp,
  @last_lat := lat AS llat,
  @last_lng := lng AS llng
 FROM v
  INNER JOIN (
   SELECT lat, lng
   FROM v
   GROUP BY lat, lng
   HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
   ) AS vg
   USING (lat, lng) 
 ORDER BY lat, lng
) AS vv

ORDER BY orgGrp
;
```

[SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!8/86d3c/28)

Comment: if your group always have 5 columns, initialize @grp := -5.. This wil do the trick http://sqlfiddle.com/#!8/86d3c/46

Comment: The groups have always different size. But your query seams to work. Can you explain how it works? Thanks!

Comment: In this - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!8/86d3c/2 fiddle, the subquery executes first and results in a group of 5. When you are selecting from 'vv', the condition will be checked again and if lat and lng are not same with previous one, 1 will get added. If you are able to initialize negative of max(group number) from the subquery, it will do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the ability to alter the schema? You would be better off normalizing that name column into a few columns: instead of

```
id | lat | lng | l | name
```

Your columns should be

```
id | lat | lng | l | groupOrSingle | groupid | memberid
```

Then writing the query would be trivial, not to mention run way more efficiently as you would be able to index the grouping information that you are querying on.

Comment: No, I can't change the schema. And this groups are actually nothing I want - I search whit this query for wrong entries which should be fixed. Also the names here are just to easier see which data it is. In the real data, they are different and unrelated to any group.